# Change values in a variable based on a conditional value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, nibble

I want to change values in my `username` variable but only when they meet a condition set from the variable `chatforum`. For example, I want all instances of users called "Alex" from Canadian chatrooms to be relabeled as "AlexCA":

```
# mock dataset
library(tidyverse)
username <- c("Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex")
id <- c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1001)
chatforum <- c("Canada", "U.S.", "U.K.", "Canada")

df <- cbind(username, id, chatforum)
df <- as_tibble(df)
glimpse(df)

df <- df  %>% filter(chatforum=="Canada") %>% 
  mutate(username = replace(username, username == "Alex", "AlexCA"))
```

Though the code above works, I want the entire dataset returned to me, *with* the changes I just made. Using `filter` returns a dataset with only the filtered rows, not the entire dataset.

I was advised to use `if_else` or `case_when()` but this also changes the username `Alice` to `AlexCA`, when I only want the `username` "Alex" to change when `chatroom == Canada`:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(username = if_else(chatforum=="Canada", "AlexCA", username))
```

Do you know how I can change the values in my `username` column based on the condition that the value is `Alex` *and* the `chatroom` value is equal to `Canada`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using `case_when` or `ifelse`, you can have multiple conditions that must be met in order to the apply the change. So, if `chatforum == "Canada" & username == "Alex"`, then we change the name to `AlexCA`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(username = case_when(
    chatforum == "Canada" & username == "Alex" ~ "AlexCA",
    TRUE ~ username
  ))
```

Or in base R:

```
df[df$chatforum == "Canada" & df$username == "Alex",]$username <- "AlexCA"
```

**Output**

```
  username id    chatforum
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>    
1 AlexCA   1001  Canada   
2 Alex     1002  U.S.     
3 Alex     1003  U.K.     
4 AlexCA   1001  Canada
```

But if you need to do this for a lot of countries, then you might want to create a key or add a new column with the abbreviation you want. For example, you could do something like this, where we create an abbreviation from the `chatforum`, then combine it with the `username`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(abrv = toupper(substr(str_replace_all(chatforum, "[[:punct:]]", ""), 1, 2))) %>%
  unite(username, c(username, abrv), sep = "")

#  username id    chatforum
#  <chr>    <chr> <chr>    
#1 AlexCA   1001  Canada   
#2 AlexUS   1002  U.S.     
#3 AlexUK   1003  U.K.     
#4 AlexCA   1001  Canada
```

Or instead of uniting after creating an abbreviation column, you could still use `case_when` for certain conditions.

```
df %>%
  mutate(abrv = toupper(substr(str_replace_all(chatforum, "[[:punct:]]", ""), 1, 2))) %>%
  mutate(username = case_when(
    chatforum == "Canada" & username == "Alex" ~ paste0(username, abrv),
    TRUE ~ username
  ))

#  username id    chatforum abrv 
#  <chr>    <chr> <chr>     <chr>
#1 AlexCA   1001  Canada    CA   
#2 Alex     1002  U.S.      US   
#3 Alex     1003  U.K.      UK   
#4 AlexCA   1001  Canada    CA
```